# Set of orthogonal matrix over $\Bbb{R}$: Closed, convex, open?

Tags: general-topology

Reading my course on topology we haven't answering this exercise:

> Show that the set of orthogonal matrix over $\Bbb{R}$ is closed. Is it convex? Open

For the fact is closed I wrote $\mathcal{O}_n(\Bbb{R})=f^{-1}\{I_n\}$ where $f:M \rightarrow M^{T}M$ is continuous.

For the convexity I think the answer is no because $I_n$ and $-I_n$ are orthogonal but the midpoint of the segment joining these two matrices is $0$ witch is not orthogonal. I am stuck for the last question. I am terrible to prove something is open or not.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You have answered the first two parts correctly. The last part is quite trivial: The set $\Omega$ of all $(n\times n)$-matrices is obviously connected. Therefore ${\cal O}(n)$ could only be closed and open at the same time if it were all of $\Omega$.

Comment: I was focus on the main definition. I should have thought about it. Thank you @ChristianBlatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** When is a diagonal matrix orthogonal? Can you find diagonal non-orthogonal matrices $(D_m)$ such that $D_m \to I_n$?

Comment: A diagonal matrix is orthogonal if $D=D^{-1}$. For the your second question I don't understand do you want a diagonal matrix of order $n$ such that the coefficient are $m$-dependent and $D$ converges to $I_n$ as $m\rightarrow +\infty$? Anyway I don't understand how can I relate this with the fact $O_n$ is not open?

Comment: If $O(n)$ were open, there would exist a open neighborhood around $I_n$, so that any sequence converging to $I_n$ would be eventually in $O(n)$.

Comment: I never thought about that. So $Diag(1+1/m,1,\cdots,1_n)$ will do the job?

Comment: Absolutely, it works.

Comment: Thank to you now I have an another way to thing about open set. +1 and accept.